# How to globally make CGridView use "raw" as the default type of CDataColumn?

Tags: php, yii

Is there a global setting in Yii to change the htmlentity display from `"&copy;" to "©"`
for admin(ajax grid)/view/ and edit views?

I found that in the CGridView parameters, I can go and update each column to `'type'=>'raw'` like below, but I will need to do this in twenty Models, and and each view manually unless I can do its globally somewhere. I have a script that imports the data with  `&copy;`, and when the customers go to edit an item, they would like to see `©`. Any help is appritiated!

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(

        'id'=>'item-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
        'filter'=>$model,

        'columns'=>array(
                'id',
                'price1',
                'price1label',
                'price2',
                'price2label',
                array('name'=>'name','type'=>'raw'), // this will display the raw entity
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such functionality built into Yii, but as is usually the case you can extend a couple of classes to achieve the aim.

First off, note that [this](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.10/framework/zii/widgets/grid/CDataColumn.php#51) is the property whose default value you 'd like to change. If you could¹ do that, then all the problems would go away.

Since you can't, you need to extend `CDataColumn` to achieve this. Dead simple:

```
Yii::import('zii.widgets.grid.CDataColumn');

class SpecialDataColumn extends CDataColumn {
    public $type = 'raw'; // that's all!
}
```

Now the problem is that you also need to tell Yii to use your special column class instead of the built-in. You can do this by specifying the `type` of each column in the `CGridView` instantiation, but that's not acceptable because you still have the problem of needing to edit every column in every view. So we 'll have to look into how `CGridView` decides to use a `CDataColumn` and override that.

Grepping a little shows that [this](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.10/framework/zii/widgets/grid/CGridView.php#287) is the code you need to modify. Specifically, there are two lines of interest:

```
$column=$this->createDataColumn($column);
```

and

```
$column['class']='CDataColumn';
```

So, you need to override the `createDataColumn` method (to change what the first line does) and the `initColumns` method (to edit the second line). Here we go:

```
Yii::import('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView');

class SpecialGridView extends CGridView {
    protected function initColumns() {
        // copy all of the stock implementation code, changing only
        // $column['class']='CDataColumn' to $column['class']='SpecialDataColumn'
    }

    protected function createDataColumn($text)
    {
        // copy all of the stock implementation code, changing only
        // $column=new CDataColumn($this) to $column=new SpecialDataColumn($this)
    }
}
```

After this is done, you are just one more edit away from happiness:

```
this->widget('SpecialGridView', ...);
```

You still need to make this edit in every view that uses a data grid, but that shouldn't take more than a few seconds with find/replace.

---

¹ Actually, you *can* simply go to that file inside the framework sources, edit a few characters, save, problem solved. The problem with this approach is that if you upgrade to a later version of Yii, your application will revert to the old behavior without warning. I don't recommend it.

Comment: How and where are the files stored? in extensions and using a folder name space or simply a file?

Answer (score 1):

Look into Yii's [widgetfactory](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.theming#customizing-widgets-globally) settings. I'm not sure if it will let you specify options for a CDataColumn, but this is where you'd be able to do it it you can

Edit: looks like you can't override CGridColumn settings that way, as it doesn't inherit directly from the widget class. So your best bet might be to override CGridView, specify a custom class for your default column and set the public variable type='raw' that way.

You might be able to use the widgetfactory to override the default class for CGridView, but I haven't done that. So you might be forced to update all your CGridView locations to use your new CGridView class override.